# Что можно передать в качестве значения параметра tzinfo при создании time для планировщика run_daily из PyTelegramBot?

Tags: python, telebot, datetime, timezone, jobscheduler

У меня стояла задача отправлять ботом, в заданное время, ежедневно, сообщение в чат.

```
from datetime import time

from telegram.ext import Updater, CallbackContext


CHAT_ID = 000000000


def notify_assignees_morning(context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text="Напоминание")


def main():
    updater = Updater("API_TOKEN")
    jq = updater.job_queue

    jq.run_daily(notify_assignees_morning, time(9, 00, 00))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Отправка сообщения производилась на 3 часа раньше (живу по Московскому времени)

Я посмотрел, что в создаваемом мной времени `time(9, 00, 00)`, есть дополнительный аргумент `tzinfo`
Но я не мог разобраться, что именно необходимо передавать в него.

В [документации](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) указано, что:

> `time (datetime.time)` – Время суток, в которое должно выполняться задание. Если часовой пояс (`time.tzinfo`) равен `None`, то будет использоваться часовой пояс бота по умолчанию.

Для меня пока так и осталось вопросом: *Где узнать часовой пояс бота по умолчанию?*

Естественно я начал пробовать передавать различные данные из библиотеки datetime и искать подробности и в какой-то момент нашел [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-a-timezone-aware-datetime-object) вопрос в котором во втором ответе нашел следующее `tzinfo=timezone.utc`
Интерпретатор выдал следующую ошибку:

> raise TypeError('Only timezones from the pytz library are supported')
> TypeError: Only timezones from the pytz library are supported

https://pypi.org/project/pytz/ на страничке библиотеки я нашел в примерах `utc = pytz.utc` соответственно попробовал, ошибок не было, но и время отправки сообщения не изменилось. (на 3 часа раньше нужно было указывать)

Решение в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Решением оказалось достаточно простым, но не явным, по крайней мере для меня.

Так как параметр называется `tzinfo` - информация о временной зоне, то и какая-то аналогичная временная зона должна быть в виде значения для него.
Посмотрев на библиотеку и примеры на той же [странице](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) pypi.org, я подумал, что нужно использовать тайм зоны, которые прописаны списком в папке `zoneinfo`

В итоге понадобилось добавить один импорт и описать временную зону по примеру `timezone('US/Eastern')` и передать в параметр `tzinfo`

```
from pytz import timezone
```

```
jq.run_daily(notify_assignees_morning, time(9, 00, 00, tzinfo=timezone('Europe/Moscow')))
```